# Selecting a rows from a pandas frame based on a time that has been converted into datetime format and stripped from a POSIX time stamp, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, pandas, posixlt

I am using the code below to pull data from Google Finance. The timestamp is in POSIX form, so it is converted into data time. When I try to filter it based on a time criteria **(14:35:00)**, it returns an empty table. I suspect it has to do with the POSIX/ datetime conversion, but have no idea how to resolve it.

```
def get_intraday_data(symbol, interval_seconds=301, num_days=10):
    # Specify URL string based on function inputs.
    url_string = 'http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q={0}'.format(symbol.upper())
    url_string += "&i={0}&p={1}d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v".format(interval_seconds,num_days)

    # Request the text, and split by each line
    r = requests.get(url_string).text.split()

    # Split each line by a comma, starting at the 8th line
    r = [line.split(',') for line in r[7:]]

    # Save data in Pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(r, columns=['Datetime','Close','High','Low','Open','Volume'])

    # Convert UNIX to Datetime format
    df['Datetime'] = df['Datetime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x[1:])))

    #Seperate Date and Time
    df['Time'],df['Date']= df['Datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.time()), df['Datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.date()) 

    #Convert 'Close','High','Low','Open', deleting 'Volume'

''''df['Close'] = df['Close'].astype('float64')
df['High'] = df['High'].astype('float64')
df['Low'] = df['Low'].astype('float64')
df['Open'] = df['Open'].astype('float64')'''
    del df['Volume']
    del df['Datetime']

    df[['Close','High','Low','Open']]  = df[['Close','High','Low','Open']].astype('float64')

   # Calculating %Change and Range 

    df['%pct'] = (df['Close'] - df['Open'])/df['Open']
    df['Range'] = df['High'] - df['Low']

    #Sort Columns


    return df
```

I have stored the results of this function as **NAS**

```
NAS = get_intraday_data('IXIC', interval_seconds=301, num_days= 100)
```

The Filter Criteria is:

```
NAS[NAS['Time'] == '14:35:00']
```

I will appreciate assistance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are converting `timestamp` to `datetime` incorrectly. You are calling `datetime` twice.

Replace

```
df['Datetime'] = df['Datetime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x[1:])))
```

with

```
df['Datetime'] = df['Datetime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x[1:])))
```

In 2nd part of your question:

```
NAS = get_intraday_data('IXIC', interval_seconds=301, num_days= 100)

NAS[NAS['Time'] == '14:35:00']
```

You care comparing instance of `datetime.time` with string, which is not correct. Try

```
NAS[NAS['Time'] == datetime.strptime('14:35:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()]
```

it should work as expected.

**Update:**

Running script with suggested changes will display data as:

`Close      High       Low      Open      Time        Date      %pct

60    5162.448  5165.124  5162.448  5165.057  14:35:00  2016-07-29 -0.000505

138   5181.768  5183.184  5181.193  5181.404  14:35:00  2016-08-01  0.000070

216   5130.514  5131.933  5130.434  5131.893  14:35:00  2016-08-02 -0.000269

294   5146.608  5146.608  5143.827  5144.788  14:35:00  2016-08-03  0.000354

372   5163.854  5164.154  5162.997  5164.021  14:35:00  2016-08-04 -0.000032

450   5221.624  5221.911  5220.658  5220.789  14:35:00  2016-08-05  0.000160

528   5204.111  5204.240  5202.476  5202.865  14:35:00  2016-08-08  0.000239

.
.
. 
3648  5282.999  5283.017  5279.008  5279.340  14:35:00  2016-10-04  0.000693

3726  5324.450  5325.375  5323.628  5324.129  14:35:00  2016-10-05  0.000060

3804  5310.945  5311.454  5310.194  5310.558  14:35:00  2016-10-06  0.000073

3882  5295.064  5295.080  5292.184  5292.327  14:35:00  2016-10-07  0.000517`

Comment: Thanks for helping. This method doesnt work. The problem  is what the next line which strips the datetime into a date and a time. The method I have used converts it from an object64 date time into time. I think the solution revolves around converting it back into an object 64. Unfortunately the time object cannot be converted directly into an object 64. A possible solution might be to convert this back into a string , and them a date time. Seems convoluted. There must be a more direct method @Saleem

Comment: @Data_Kid what do you mean it's not working? Have you gave it a try? I'm able to filter and display dataframe for give time

Comment: that's strange. When I took out one date time it threw out an attribute error. I have found a work around that works..will post it later as I have run into other issues I am trying to resolve now

Comment: I have just seen the edit. It works like a charm!! thanks!

Comment: @Data_Kid, asking for upvote is not a good idea. Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323847/is-it-okay-to-ask-for-upvotes-in-a-question

Comment: very new to the platform. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
NAS.query('Datetime.dt.hour==14 and Datetime.dt.minute==35 and Datetime.dt.second==0')
```

**Edit:**
Applied dt on datetime series instead of time series

```
raw_data = {'Datetime': ['2015-05-01T14:35:00', '2016-07-04T02:26:00', '2013-02-01T04:41:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Datetime'])
df["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Datetime"])
df['Time'],df['Date']= df['Datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.time()), df['Datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.date()) 
df = df.set_index(df["Datetime"])
df['hour']=df['Datetime'].dt.hour
df['minute']=df['Datetime'].dt.minute
df['second']=df['Datetime'].dt.second
df.query('Datetime.dt.hour==14 and Datetime.dt.minute==35 and Datetime.dt.second==0')
```

Comment: I get  an error: 

`AttributeError: 'Load' object has no attribute '__name__'` @userRaj

Comment: You can also try this one ,NAS[NAS['Time'].hour==14 & NAS['Time'].minute==35 & NAS['Time'].second==00 ]

Comment: I still get an error:
This time it is `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'` @userRaj